# How to do editable data grid in wpf using mvvm?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I want to use a editable data grid, to add, edit data. Is it possible with wpf? Can some one give an the example?

Comment: Why not? datagrid is precisely made for this purpose. Here is a good link to get you started: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

Comment: http://brentedwards.net/2012/03/11/wpf-datagridrow-double-click-with-mvvm/

Answer (score 21):

[DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) controls has all that functionality built-in. You can set the properties [CanUserAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true to allow user to add rows.

`DataGrid` is editable by default, where each column has an edit control which lets you edit its value. By default the `DataGrid` automatically generates columns for every property in your *Model*, so you don't even have to define it's columns.

Here are some good links with detailed examples you can look into:

http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/

Good luck

Comment: I just found if your `ItemSource` Binding to a `IEnumerable` will cause the data can't be editable, I change `IEnumerable` into `List` then it can be edited noramally

Comment: I populate the dataGrid through code from a .mdbx database table and setting "CanUserAddRows" to true made adding records possible. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Have a Xaml as below

```
<Window x:Class="DatGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DatGrid">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Values}"></DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

In the ViewModel is very simple some thing like below

```
class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Example> Values
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
public class Example
{
    public string A
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string B
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

In the view you can always see a empty row you can just click and type something and press enter it'll get updated to the ViewModel

Comment: Updating the bound viewmodel properties is only a tiny. tiny bit of what is required for editing. E.g. what about command(s) to persist the data?